# tensorflow AttributError: type object 'NewBase' has no attribute 'is_abstract'

Tags: python, tensorflow

Already upgraded six. pip sucessfully installed tensorflow. Went through several steps/upgrades just to get to this point. Now, when I try to import into python that this error comes up.

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 106, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.platform import test
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/test.py", line 67, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.framework import test_util as _test_util
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/test_util.py", line 43, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.platform import googletest
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/googletest.py", line 32, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.platform import benchmark  # pylint: disable=unused-import
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/benchmark.py", line 119, in <module>
class Benchmark(six.with_metaclass(_BenchmarkRegistrar, object)):
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.py", line 566, in with_metaclass
return meta("NewBase", bases, {})
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/benchmark.py", line 114, in __new__
if not newclass.is_abstract():
AttributeError: type object 'NewBase' has no attribute 'is_abstract'
```

Help!

Answer (score 1):

That's because your "six" package is out-of-date. Please do below:

1. check your six version via: python; import six; print(six.**version**)
2. If version < 1.10, then you need to upgrade six to newer version
3. sudo easy_install --upgrade six
4. check again six version and make sure the version >= 1.10
5. redo python; import tensorflow as tf;

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading six will resolve the issue. 
TensorFlow requires [six => 1.10](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/setup.py#L41) - to check the six version, via interpreter:

```
$ python
>>>import six
>>>print six.\__version\__
```

Or, you can simply check it using pip:

```
$ pip show six
```

If you have six version less than 1.10, upgrade it:

```
$ pip install --upgrade six
```

Answer (score 0):

It might to be too late, but I put a suggestion.

In case of Mac OS X, the Python modules can be placed in two different places and this might to cause the problem.

Please check the module, six, this case, in:

- /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
- /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

If you find an older version in the folder/file, delete it.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue but likely for a different reason.  I happen to have a package called rdkit also installed (recently).  It happens to have a much older version of six.py embedded (v1.6.1 why - idk?).  However, I was able to copy in a newer replacement for six.py and it fixed everything after adding a small fix to rdkit as well.  For work I am doing I need rdkit in the same environment unfortunately.  I guess this is something else to look for if you work with packages that use their own version of six.py.